# ASP.Net Core certificate authentication behind Azure Application Proxy

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core

I wrote a small ASP.Net Core application that uses for the API route a certificate authentication. The Web-App is running on a Windows Server with IIS. Running the PWSH command:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -uri https://servername/api -Certificate $cert
```

runs fine when I call it from the local network.

Now I set up an Azure Application Proxy with Passthrough authentication. I can reach the website (non-api) with a browser and can work with it. However, when I try to use the PowerShell Command I get on the IIS log a 403 0 0 9.

In my understanding, at least the request is getting to the local server, but then the certificate does not getting validated?!??

I also tried adding:

```
builder.Services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ForwardedHeaders =
        ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
});
```

but honestly I am not sure what it is doing. I also don't know how to debug the app in a better way with VSC.

I also added the a logger to the Certificate Authentication so see if this gets triggered, but it doesn't when using the Azure App Proxy.

Can maybe someone help me with that, let me check how I can better debug it?

Thanks in advance
Stephan